# Opening FileName:LineNumber in Xcode from AppCode

Tags: xcode, app-code, appcode, javascript-automation

I want switch from AppCode to Xcode and continue editing **file** on the same **line**.

Solution based on UI Automation seems working.
Is the are any solution how to do the same without UI Automation; without need of showing `Open Quickly` dialog and typing `FileName:LineNumber`?

Thanks!

---

Solution based on UI Automation.
The code below will open `File -> Open Quickly ...` dialog, then will type into `File or Symbol` search field and finally will hit `Enter`:

```js
//
// File: openFileInXcode.scpt
//
function run(argv) {
    locationToOpen = argv[0]
    if (locationToOpen == undefined) {
        doSysLog("Nothing to do. Exiting...")
        return
    }
    openFileinXcode(locationToOpen)
}

function openFileinXcode(location) {
    var appXcode = Application('Xcode')
    appXcode.activate()
    doSysLog("Opening file: " + location)
    delay(0.2)

    var appSysEvents = Application('System Events')
    appSysEvents.keystroke('o', { using: ['command down', 'shift down'] })
    appSysEvents.keystroke(location)
    appSysEvents.keyCode(36)
}

function doSysLog(message) {
    app = Application.currentApplication()
    app.includeStandardAdditions = true
    app.doShellScript('syslog -s -l W "WaveLabs Automation: ' + message + '"')
    console.log(message)
}
```

Usage from command line:

```sh
 osascript -l JavaScript "/path/to/openFileInXcode.scpt" "AppDelegate.swift:11"
```

Usage from AppCode:

1. Go to `File -> Preferences -> Tools -> External Tools`
2. Add new tool and configure parameters using macros (i.e. `$FileName$:$LineNumber$`)

**Update 07.06.2016**: Detail description of `External Tool` setup:

- Program: `/bin/bash`
- Parameters: `-c "[[ -r ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc; osascript -l JavaScript \"$PATH_TO_YOUR_SCRIPTS_DIR/OpenFileInXcode.scpt\" \"$FileName$:$LineNumber$\""`
- Working directory: `$ProjectFileDir$`

Comment: How do you configure the tool in AppCode? I'm getting an `syntax error near unexpected token `argv'` error when running the script from AppCode.

Comment: I did a trick shown in original post under section "Update 07.06.2016". Idea behind that we launching bash with option `-c`. So, that bash execute commands from passed string ,)

Comment: FYI, `xed -l $LineNumber$ $FilePath$` is a shorter method, but for some reason that does not go to the line right away, there's a short delay.